# MSTest setup/teardown methods that run before and after ALL tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, nunit, mstest, xunit

Relatively new to MSTest v2 in Visual Studio 2019. The `TestInitialize` attribute indicates the method should run **before** each and every test. Similarly, `TestCleanup` indicates the method should run **after** each and every test.

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Setup()
{
    // This method will be called before each MSTest test method
}

[TestCleanup()]
public void Teardown()
{
    // This method will be called after each MSTest test method has completed
}
```

If your test class has N methods, the above methods will run N times.

Is there a way to signal setup and teardown-like methods that run once only? In other words, for each complete run through all N tests, each method will run once only.

Are there similar mechanisms for NUnit3 and xUnit v2.4.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some hunting, I stumbled on [this website with a MSTest "Cheat Sheet"](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/mstest-cheat-sheet/) which has examples of what I was looking for (in MSTest):

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void TestFixtureSetup(TestContext context)
{
    // Called once before any MSTest test method has started (optional)
}

[ClassCleanup]
public static void TestFixtureTearDown()
{
    // Called once after all MSTest test methods have completed (optional)
}
```

The `ClassInitialize` method must be public, static, return void and takes a single parameter. The `ClassCleanup` method must be public, static, return void and takes no parameters.

For NUnit, the attribute references can be [found here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/):

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void TestFixtureSetup()
{
    // Called once before any NUnit test method has started (optional)
}

[OneTimeTearDown]
public void TestFixtureTearDown()
{
    // Called once after all NUnit test methods have completed (optional)
}
```

The `OneTimeSetUp` method must be public, but can be static or an instance method. Same for the `OneTimeTearDown` method.

xUnit does not appear to support the `Setup` / `Teardown` feature.

Comment: The [ClassInitialize] is one-time triggered method before test cases start.
The [TestInitialize] is triggered before every test case.